# Update Android widget on system settings change

Tags: android, android-widget

There are a lot of threads/questions on stackoverflow about updating widgets, updating apps on system setting changes, etc, but I can't seem to find the exact answer to my question.

How do I update a widget when a system setting is changed?  I.e., the Power Control widget has toggles for bluetooth, GPS, sync, etc.  When one of those settings is changed via the Settings app, the widget is automatically updated.  For apps, I believe registerContentObserver would work.  However, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483651/appwidgetprovider-not-called-onenabled-method) indicates registerContentObserver will not work in widgets.

Do I have to create a service just to registerContentObserver?  Or is this accomplished in a different manner?